# ¿Como borrar un registro de Entity con una consulta linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Lo que quiero es borrar un registro de entity framework a travez de una consulta de linq solo que me da un ligero error:

codigo de la consulta linq:

```
var context = GetDbContext();

        var listadoV = from Ar in context.archivo
                              where Ar.url.Contains(elemento)
                              select new FileNedera()
                              {
                                  Url = Ar.url,
                              };

        context.archivo.Remove(listadoV);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Me marca un error en la siguiente linea  `context.archivo.Remove(listadoV);` y me dice lo siguiente:

```
Cannot convert from system.Linq.IEqueryable to Ned4AccesData.Archivo
```

Tambien lo intente de la siguiente forma:

```
context.BloqueoExcursion.RemoveRange(cSelect);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var context = GetDbContext();

var listadoV = from Ar in context.archivo
                   where Ar.url.Contains(elemento)
                   select Ar;

context.archivo.Remove(listadoV);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Explicación:

En tu código, al hacer uso de `select new FileNedera()`, estás cambiando la estructura original porque creas una nueva clase del filtrado que estás realizando.